# System of Schrodinger equations

Tags: sturm-liouville

I know that Schrodinger equation for 1 dimension is given by:
$-u''+qu=\lambda u$ and if I want to work on a system for say 2 dimensions,
the system would be:
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{c} -u_1''\\ -u_2'' \end{array}\right)
+\left(\begin{array}{cc} q_1 & q_2\\ q_3 & q_4\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c} u_1 \\ u_2 \end{array}\right)
=\lambda \left(\begin{array}{c} u_1 \\ u_2 \end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
My question is: is this system right and does make sense? and if the q in 1 dimension is periodic can I make the matrix $Q$ in this system: 
\begin{equation}
Q=\left(\begin{array}{cc} q_1 & q_2\\ q_3 & q_4\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
to be periodic?
If this system I made is correct, is there any examples for this case of system in quantum mechanics or other field of applications?

Comment: System looks right, this equation does appear for multi particle systems, when you consider the tensor product of Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Can you recommend some references which talk about this system?

Comment: Maybe have a look at the treatment of magnetic resonance in Townsends book "A Modern Approach to Quantum Mechanics"